# get hold of UIResponder instance methods on UIScrollView. iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, touch-event, uiresponder

on the current project I am working on, on one of the views, I have a `UIView` and on top of it `UIScrollView` which is constructed from the interface builder.

I have implemented the following `UIResponder` instance methods:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

but the control comes to this methods only when touch event occur in area where is not covered by the `UIScrollView`.

how I can get the hold of a touch event on the `UIScrollView` also?

Comment: Can you show the code where you initialize the scrollView and the code for the view controller that it is contained in? Add the code as an update to your question so the code formatter can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could create a subclass of UIScrollView and override:

```
- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view
```

you have to be careful that you don't interfere with the scrolling gestures etc tho.

Comment: thanx Mike, I got it working by subclaseing  UIScrollView and implementing the bove two metods with in this class.